# Java: adding Image to JTable?

Tags: java, swing

I have a big button when clicked , adds an image to a table

```
    class BigButtonListener implements ActionListener{
 Image screenshot=null;
 Browser bigbrowser =null;

 BigButtonListener(Browser browser, DefaultTableModel dataModel, DefaultTableModel historyModel, JTable dataTable, JTable historyTable) {
  screenshot = browser.toImage(true);
  bigbrowser = browser;
  historyTable = historyTable;
  //table1.addRow
 }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   // save current image
   historyModel.insertRow(0,new Object[]{new ImageIcon(screenshot)}); 
   //System.out.println(historyTable.getRowCount());

  }   
}
```

however, all this adds is the text `javax.swing.ImageIcon@9dfb04` and not the actual picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultTableCellRenderer` extends JLabel and renders by simply `setText(value.toString())`.

Follow the [definite Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) on custom cell renderer and editor.

Or use simple hack like this:

```
historyTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    protected void setValue(Object value) {
        if( value instanceof ImageIcon ) {
            setIcon((ImageIcon)value);
            setText("");
        } else {
            setIcon(null);
            super.setValue(value);
        }
    }
});
```